# Python - Context menu on Mac/Windows - Right click on .docx to convert to .pdf

Tags: python, windows, macos, contextmenu

I have been searching all over the internet for an answer to my question (see below) but without any luck. I am therefore reaching out here on stackoverflow to perhaps find the answer.

I want to right click on a (and multiple) .docx in a folder and be able to run a standalone python-app which converts the selected .docx to .pdf. The "only" problem I have is how i get the input (the selected files which I want to convert) as a list which is provided to the standalone app? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: See answer from `sphil` here... https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/what-is-best-method-to-get-list-of-names-of-finder-selection/531/2 You can run Applescript from Terminal (or Python) using `osascript` command.